# How to show text using byte array instead of string using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

```
private void ShowText(PdfContentByte cb, BaseFont bf , float height , int align , float posX , float posY , int rotation , byte[] buf)
{
    string msg = Encoding.Default.GetString( buf );
    cb.SaveState();
    cb.BeginText();
    cb.SetFontAndSize( bf , height );
    //use string
    cb.ShowTextAligned( align , msg , posX , posY , rotation );
    //want to use byte array
    cb.ShowTextAligned( align , buf , posX , posY , rotation );
    cb.EndText();
    cb.RestoreState();
}
```

I want to use a byte array to show the text.
I have a custom font which has some characters in untypable area.

Is it possible to use a byte array instead of converting it to a string?

Comment: Why, when you can just call `GetString`, as you're doing?

Comment: Try `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.Default`..

Comment: `Encoding.Unicode` doesn't work. Because byte array was created based on ascii text.

Comment: Then which range of ASCII characters is your custom font using?

Comment: it's code ranges are 0x20 - 0x7F, 0xA1 - oxAB.

Comment: It is barcode font and data was created as encoded binary string from other program- I cannot change the data. It's code ranges are 0x20 - 0x7F, 0xA1 - oxAB. My O/S is Windows 8.1 professional Korean. the code range  0xA1 ~ 0xAB is treated as DBCS(double byte), then characters are missing within this range.

Comment: You have two problems to solve. First, the barcode font doesn't necessarily has the characters in the place you think it has and in many cases, unless it's a plain code 39 barcode, you'll need some codification made beforehand. Second, you must know what kind of data comes from the array, it can already be encoded for the font or it can be plain text in DBCS and can be converted to string with the appropriated encoding. If it's the last case I suspect that you'll have to return to the first case to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your detaild answer. I mean characters are barcode lines that treated as characters in the barcode font. The input data is byte array from another program and are already encoded to assign the barcode font characters. when the byte array has this values -  0xAA 22 20 52 68 56 26 62 2A 60 3F 42 67 A4 30 75 AB. And that bytes is point the barcode font character without any other operations.It cannot be converted back to plain text.

Comment: I decided that barcode data within DBCS range move to SBCS range. barcode font changed as this 0xA1 ~ 0xAB => 0x11 ~ 0x1B and data also changed to new mapping before create PDF. Thank you all.